# How to check current URL inside @if statement in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.6 and im trying to check if my current URL inside an `@if` statement.

I saw some other posts stating that it could be done like this `@if(Request:url() === 'url to check')`. But that particular post i saw was the solution for Laravel 4. Anyone knows how to get the current url and put inside an `@if` statement for Laravel 5.6?

**Example**

```
@if(Request::url() === '/dashboard/attendance/report')
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">Button</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would tackle this the following way.

```
@if(str_contains(url()->current(), '/dashboard/attendance/report'))
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">Button</a>
@endif
```

The `str_contains()` function checks whether the string (parameter #1) contains the second string. I prefer this function because the Laravel `url()` function returns a full url, whereas you would like to check whether the url contains a certain path.

Documentation for the `url()->current()` can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#accessing-the-current-url

**Edit:**
A way to ensure that `/dashboard/attendance/report` is at the end of the current url, you could use the following:

```
@if(substr(url()->current(), -1) == '/dashboard/attendance/report'))
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">Button</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be checking for URL's, you should be checking for routes. I would do it this way.

```
@if (request()->is('admin/myRoute'))
[do stuff]
@endif
```

Comment: How would you check if the current route, was relating to a route. i.e. route()->startsWith('myRoute/')